# How to uninstall Git?

Tags: terminal, git

Anyone know how to uninstall Git?

I would like to uninstall Git using the Uninstall.sh file that came in the git-2.0.1 install bundle.

I am unable to find the Uninstall.sh file using Terminal. When I enter "git --version" in the command line, I get "Illegal Instruction" in my Terminal window. (See image below).

I would like to uninstall Git and then reinstall it. Perhaps the Git download was corrupt. Any ideas? I am running Mac OS 10.6.8.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you need to do

```
cd "/Volumes/Git 2.0.1 Snow Leopard Intel Universal"
sudo bash uninstall.sh
```

?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I was able to uninstall Git using your string. But, I tried to reinstall it again and I'm still getting "Illegal Instruction" in my Terminal window when I type "git --version". Any ideas why that is happening? Someone said it might be a bad Git download so I downloaded again from Git-scm.com (via SourceForge.net) Again...THX!

Comment: I guess re-install is a better solution, as some software installation may use Git.