# How to uninstall Git from the command shell?

Tags: git

I currently have installed

```
git --version
git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
```

At this path

```
which git
/usr/bin/git
```

In a previous answer 
[How to uninstall Git?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146503/how-to-uninstall-git?rq=1) 
it was suggested to run the `uninstall.sh`, but if I run `cd /usr/bin/git` I get `-bash: cd: /usr/bin/git: Not a directory`.

Below I copied the output of `ls -l` on the directory `usr/bin` (only the files that look to me as related to git for reasons of space).

```
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     18176 Mar 12 09:08 git
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     18208 Mar 12 09:08 git-cvsserver
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     18208 Mar 12 09:08 git-receive-pack
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     18192 Mar 12 09:08 git-shell
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     18208 Mar 12 09:08 git-upload-archive
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel     18208 Mar 12 09:08 git-upload-pack
```

How do I uninstall git? I am trying to **update to a newer version**, the installer runs successfully, but when I run `git --version` I still get the older version. Thus I was thinking to uninstall git and reinstall from scratch, not sure if this is the right approach tho.

Comment: `cd /usr/bin` then `ls -l` and post results please?

Comment: @emotality Thanks, I've added it. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Which answer suggested removing it? It needs to be heavily down voted as it is not a good idea.and you should not install git in /usr/bin/git (in fact doing that is quite difficult so how did you manage it)

Comment: If the question you saw was http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146503/how-to-uninstall-git?rq=1 note that that git us not in /usr/bin/git and there is a directory which in your case you have apple's got and there is not git directory

Comment: @Mark I forgot to add the link, but that's exactly the question I am referring to. I am not sure why I have the wrong directory, it is possible that updating to El Capitan might have changed something in the git location? Anyway, given I have git in the wrong directory I am not sure I understand your recommendation on how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, where do you get new version from? Maybe Homebrew?

Comment: The `/usr/bin/git*` files are a default part of OS X and there is not an uninstaller for the OS X default version of `git`.

Comment: @techraf from here https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: @techraf Thanks it worked like a charm, I am not sure this is strictly an answer to my original question, but it's actually what I needed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Do not uninstall Apple-distributed Git.** You can leave it as it is and run another version by having it in a directory earlier in `PATH` environment variable.

The easiest way to install another version on OS X would be to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) packet manager.

After installing it, you can run:

```
brew install git
```

Homebrew (`brew`) will take care of all dependencies and configure the latest Git version, however there is still a chance it will find a setting it cannot resolve automatically, so read what Homebrew says at the end.

Packages installed with `brew` do not interfere with system-preinstalled packages.
It installs packages under `/usr/local/Cellar` directory and puts executables in `/usr/local/bin`, so you just have to keep it in `PATH` variable in before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: This seems to be true, I didn't uninstall the git which was installed in usr/bin but when I installed git with homebrew it took over.

Comment: The git app in /usr/bin/git was failing for me asking to install the command line tools every time (even after it was already installed a couple of times). I also did not want to install XCode because I don't use it anymore. I then opened the Finder in the Applications folder and moved the Xcode.app to the Bin and now my git app does not ask me to install things anymore.

Answer (score 20):

For people who installed git by following instructions on [the official Git homepage](https://git-scm.com), and therefore have `git` installed at `/usr/local/bin/git`, run the uninstall script:

`/usr/local/git/uninstall.sh`

Comment: How does this uninstall `/usr/bin/git`?

Comment: @nohillside It doesn't, because git-scm.com does not install to /usr/bin/git. Updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks. If you are wondering about the downvotes, please reread the question. While your answer is correct in itself, it doesn’t directly address the question asked.

Comment: @nohillside I'm aware, but it does answer the title, and the title is the reason I clicked the article - So this answer would've helped me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot this was my problem too ... homebrew insisted I had 2.39 already installed but which git showed this version 2.15. Uninstalling as you suggest seems to have fixed things

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin/git`, along with some other cmd tools, is just a jumper binary to a real binary comes with Xcode.app or 'Xcode Command Line Tools' (CLT). It is protected by SIP and you shouldn't delete it.

You might consider to remove Xcode.app or /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ .

Comment: Excellent. I'm guessing this is the binary that's responsible for the pop-up offering to download the CLT package?

Answer (score 0):

**I had a very similar issue. Struggled with it for hours and finally found that removing/deleting my .ssh folder and generating a new ssh key did the trick.**

I ran the following in the terminal

```
rm -rf .ssh/
```

> (after rm -rf, type .ss and hit TAB, it should jump to the folder)

Your ssh folder should no longer exist

Next, generate your public key with the following command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

OR, if you want to set it up with your email address, you can type

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremailaddress@example.com"
```

This will generate a ssh key

> (Go through the process by following the prompts, set password if
>   needed)

Then, you can display your code by typing the following

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

OR

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

> (to automatically copy your public key)
>
> Finally, paste it in your GitHub or any other, as you would normally
>   add a public ssh key.

This worked very well for me.

I hope it helps a few others as well

Comment: This is a interesting answer, but I'm not sure how it relates to removing git